# How do I see the changes made in a particular module by someone in his/her changelist

Tags: perforce, p4v, p4merge

A coworker submitted a gigantic changelist (>1000 files) as part of a refactoring, and perforce just shows it as 'There are 1000 files in this changelist'.

I'd like to see the changes he made to all files in a folder/module via Perforce p4merge or IntelliJ's perforce integration/diff tool.

Answer (score 2):

In P4V go to Edit->Preferences and select "Server Data" settings at the left.

Increase setting "Maximun number of files displayed per changelist*:" to desired value (e.g. put more than 1000 for the example above) and save settings.

> *After limit is reached, changelist and resolve dialogs show plain text list of files

Comment: Thanks :) I did end up figuring that out. I would still like to see the diff of just a folder before/after thru perforce. I ended up using beyond compare.